# Problema con INPUT de angular material

Tags: web, angular4, entrada, angular-material

Tengo un problema con incluir el input de angular material a mi proyecto ya que no funciona como debe en cuanto a lo visual. Les dejo una imagen de como se ve[image: MatInput]

He seguido las instrucciones de la documentacion paso a paso y nada. Asi esta mi app module y mi respectivo componente

[image: app.module]

[image: App.module.ts]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llevo semanas con esto y no puedo arreglarlo, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que te haga falta incluir el tema.
Debes incluir el tema precargado de Angular Material en el "`styles.css`"

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Si requieres más información revisar: [Theming your Angular Material app](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

> Including a theme is required to apply all of the core and theme styles to your application. To get started with a prebuilt theme, include one of Angular Material's prebuilt themes globally in your application. If you're using the Angular CLI, you can add this to your styles.css:

Comment: Gracias!! si era eso, ahora si funciona